# KSQL Persisent Query not writing data to KSQL Table

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have two KSQL Tables each having the same key. I am running the following query on them

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP1 AS SELECT
    b.MFG_DATE,
    b.rowtime as bd_rowtime,
    s.rowtime as sd_rowtime,
    b.EXPIRY_DATE as EXP_DATE,
    b.BATCH_NO as BATCH_NO,
    s.rowkey as SD_ID
FROM GR_SD4 s
    INNER JOIN GR_BD4 b ON b.rowkey = s.rowkey;
PARTITION BY s.rowkey;
```

The resulting table does not get populated with data but when I run the select query separately it populates the data. I am confused on what could be the reason for the table not being populated with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be related to the PARTITION BY clause in your query. Since you are joining two tables, the resulting table will have a composite primary key (rowkey, s.rowkey). The PARTITION BY clause should be updated to reflect this, i.e. PARTITION BY rowkey, s.rowkey. This should ensure that the data is correctly partitioned and can be inserted into the table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try this out. I have also found out that my table had null keys which could also be the reason for the resultant table not being populated right ?

Comment: @danthelion I dont think table will have composite key. It will have only 1 key.

Comment: @vignesh1905 why do u need PARTITION BY cause from your query that will be the default value for the table. Are you doing STREAM-TABLE join?

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti I think now my problem is the null keys I am getting in one of the tables. Any suggestions on how to overcome this. I tried rekeying but my situation is that the key I am trying to join both the tables is bound to have nulls. Any suggestions on this ?

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti to answer your question. I want to partition because I am going to join another join based on the partitioned key.

Comment: @vignesh1905 As a work around Convert null as -1 or empty string in the source table. then do join. like `ifnull(<column-name>, cast(-1 as bigint))`